# How to free output of NetworkIsolationGetAppContainerConfig

Tags: c++, winapi, msdn

I am using this function [`NetworkIsolationGetAppContainerConfig`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh447481(v=vs.85).aspx)
There is an output parameter of the type `PSID_AND_ATTRIBUTES *` and there is no indication of how to free its memory.
I searched the web and couldn't find such indication.
Can you please assist me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Given that the parameter is documented as "Used for debugging purposes.", I'd say that freeing memory is not that relevant. Sure, it will leak memory, but that's not a big deal for a debugging session.

Comment: I agree, however I need to use it not only for debugging purposes so free the memory is indeed a real need.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

> Note that it is the calling program's responsibility to free the memory associated with the PSID_AND_ATTRIBUTES structure. The following code sample shows how to call this function. The FreeAppContainerConfig function shows how to free all of the associated memory.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh447481(v=vs.85).aspx